# Model design -- What's the optimal way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this app I am writing in Rails 3.1, I am wondering the best way to model this.

Would it be best if I created a model called "Movie" with a "title" and then create a new model for each "movie asset" such as "poster, trailer, screener" etc and relate it to the "Movie" by associations? Or would it be best if I just created this as one and do-away with the of associations of each asset to "Movie"?

[image: model question]

My assumption is to just make it as one as it will remove all the overhead of the FK's and joins to get retrieve the data related to the movie but I am looking for opinions/suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Can you guarantee that you'll only have 1 trailer, poster, screener, or additional asset per movie?

Comment: Yep, there can never ever be anymore than 1 asset, poster, screener etc per movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be three types of attributes(columns) for movies.

1. Which have exactly one value, and are present in every movie e.g. title, year, official trailer etc.

   - Keep them in the movie table.
2. Which have exactly one value, but are present in few of the movies e.g. total Academy Awards.

   - Keep them in separate table, and use **has_one+belongs_to** association.
3. Which have multiple values e.g. trailers

   - Keep them in separate table, and use **has_many+belongs_to** association.

More suggestions:

- For many key-value attributes, it is easier to use one json/yaml column using serialize instead of creating one column for each key.
- Do not store images in DB, keep them in file-system or cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your models in the order you want since you have to fill in both models to create a unique association (such as `belongs_to` and `has_many`) so I think it doesn't really matter !